# Gerrit client -remote configuration

Tags: gerrit

I have installed Git and Gerrit and prepared remote site.
I am facing communication issue between Client and Remote.
My Config file looks as below,
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XS090.png)

Error while doing clone,
Fatal: Could not read from remote repository
Please make sure you have the correct access rights.

Comment: Hi Amit! Please edit your question, copy/paste the code and remove the image from your post. The StackOverflow moderators are sticklers and will remove your question for not including the code as text!

Comment: How have you created the repository? Have you set the permissions? Are you using the correct user to clone?